# GNU screen, vim, and urxvt with 256 colours. gnu

Tags: vim, gnu-screen, urxvt

I have defined

```
urxvt*color0:      #000000
urxvt*color8:      #777777
```

in my $HOME/.Xdefault.  Using vim (console not gvim), this gives me a light grey for strings in bash scripts when I use urxvt.  Now, if I start GNU screen and edit the same file with vim, all strings are now black.  This is a problem since I use revese video (white text on black background for my terminal). The TERM is the same in both instances (xterm).

Is this a vim or screen issue?  More importantly, how do I solve it?

After bhinesley reply put me on the right tracks, the solution was to add

```
set t_Co=256
```

to my $HOME/.vimrc.  Also, I have the following set for my TERM variable:

```
screen-256color
xterm-256color
```

for screen and urxvt console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download and run `256colors2.pl` from here: http://www.frexx.de/xterm-256-notes/

If it doesn't look like the screenshot on the site, then you know that your problem is `screen`. If it looks fine, you can test Vim using `:runtime syntax/colortest.vim`.

Comment: AHA, thanks.  This has pointed me in the right direction.  It was neither screen (worked fine) nor vim (worked fine) but my own broken colour theme.  I shall fix that.  Thanks.